# Displaying large number of text labels on a scatter plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, correspondence-analysis, vegan

Having too many species in the data, makes the species labels overlap in a plot of a canonical correspondence analysis.  This makes it difficult to interpret. Is there a reasonable possible solution?

How can I make the plot so that it is easier to interpret? There are so many species names that they are getting overlapped. I can't delete any species in my analysis. Should (can) I make some species invisible to avoid overlapping? Should (can) I make four plots instead of one plot, making some species invisible in each?

```
# COMMUNITY DATA:
| sites     | sites1   | sites2   | sites3   | sites4   | sites5   | sites6   | sites7   | sites8   | sites9   | sites10  | sites11  |
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| Acynsgec  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.041306 | 0.478469 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Acerfugc  | 5        | 32.3303  | 1        | 0.5      | 2.01005  | 6.451987 | 0.8      | 2.270868 | 0        | 0        | 7.985437 |
| Aghimghl  | 0.515464 | 0        | 0.5      | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.010101 | 0        | 0        |
| Ahonhyte  | 2.030928 | 1.479432 | 3.004008 | 2.985222 | 11.09266 | 1.451987 | 3        | 8.980125 | 6.525353 | 3.47619  | 0.968529 |
| Aiiaspuc  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.961538 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Agaprryl  | 9.5      | 41.05951 | 4.004008 | 21.95567 | 17.41306 | 22.61291 | 9        | 7.918127 | 9.020802 | 4.904762 | 8.340298 |
| Avgrroti  | 8.092784 | 5.768965 | 3.006012 | 18.97044 | 8.330445 | 26.67578 | 4        | 11.89332 | 6.480198 | 11       | 8.437057 |
| Awqmobty  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2.470443 | 1.041306 | 0.39604  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.47619  | 1.45162  |
| Aoplspet  | 0        | 1        | 1.002004 | 0        | 3.041306 | 0.478469 | 0        | 1.923077 | 2.0002   | 1        | 1        |
| Aatespyc  | 0.5      | 0        | 1        | 1.985222 | 0        | 0.49505  | 0        | 0        | 3.030303 | 0        | 0.968529 |
| Bpobspkc  | 0        | 11.08063 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Bargsjkr  | 64.80928 | 9.469148 | 0        | 9.874385 | 45.84119 | 2.408925 | 0        | 5.307692 | 41.94139 | 9.857143 | 11.65147 |
| Browspmc  | 26       | 10.4585  | 6.212425 | 25.64532 | 12.02513 | 33.74854 | 12       | 18.74824 | 22.9713  | 40.80952 | 12.65616 |
| Byelspuc  | 4        | 0.5      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 4.784689 | 0        | 0        | 5.010101 | 4.666667 | 0.483092 |
| Buqlcane  | 0.5      | 0        | 2.002004 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.485437 |
| Cbmpodat  | 9.108247 | 2.695886 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2        |
| Ceroceqa  | 3.5      | 0        | 0        | 1.495567 | 0        | 4        | 0        | 0.961538 | 1        | 0        | 0        |
| Coaevitlo | 2        | 0.979432 | 1.502004 | 2.992611 | 2.082611 | 0        | 2        | 0        | 1.010101 | 1.952381 | 0.968529 |
| Ckcespyc  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 4.5      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Clkdpoxi  | 2        | 4.030303 | 0.1002   | 5.697044 | 0        | 6.475248 | 0        | 1.987611 | 0.49505  | 4        | 0.483092 |
| Clhnulbr  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Czdoosat  | 6.061856 | 0.979432 | 1.5      | 1.985222 | 4.082611 | 3.531195 | 3        | 2.961538 | 6.020202 | 8.5      | 1.939402 |
| Cdrycrks  | 0.406186 | 0.1      | 1.001002 | 0.298522 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2        |
| Cyryrjta  | 0        | 0        | 0.5      | 0        | 2.585124 | 2.442086 | 4        | 3.461538 | 1.0001   | 0        | 0.483092 |
| Carythjr  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2.082611 | 0.478469 | 0.5      | 0        | 0.505051 | 0        | 0        |
| Cjtooqat  | 0.515464 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Dulpcqch  | 0        | 0        | 0.501002 | 0        | 1        | 0        | 3        | 0.961538 | 1.0001   | 5.5      | 0.485437 |
| Dzzoroyl  | 0.206186 | 0        | 1.001002 | 0.985222 | 0        | 1.473518 | 0.5      | 0        | 0.99505  | 0.47619  | 0.485437 |
| Epylrohe  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Eughsprc  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 33.45057 | 8        | 1.961538 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Euuhogfi  | 0        | 0        | 1.002004 | 4.5      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2.990299 | 6.452381 | 2.903241 |
| Fareotta  | 0        |          | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.19802  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Ghlisggc  | 0        | 0        | 0.200401 | 0.8      | 1.041306 | 0.478469 | 0.5      | 0.480769 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Gmultfic  | 37.21649 | 0        | 0        | 1.970443 | 4.165223 | 0.478469 | 0        | 15.85476 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Ghntsqqc  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.49505  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Garaprrt  | 11       | 0.195886 | 1.301002 | 0.598522 | 2.585124 | 0.49505  | 0        | 1.980198 | 0.99505  | 1        | 0        |
| Germelqt  | 8        | 1.5      | 0        | 15.95567 | 7.082611 | 1.913876 | 1.5      | 10.8983  | 16.9911  | 0        | 6        |
| Grqsssttc | 28.15464 | 55.98917 | 14.01002 | 29.85222 | 34.67094 | 127.0644 | 19.94059 | 51.92873 | 68.9917  | 75.7619  | 72.09646 |
| Gqpssyyc  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |          | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Iqpathee  | 0        | 0        | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Inglrowl  | 1.515464 | 0        | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Jrrscgni  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.49505  | 0        | 0        |
| Jrniszta  | 8.247423 | 152.6249 | 445.5962 | 8.955665 | 24.99134 | 29.37136 | 448      | 60.73077 | 15.05151 | 241.1429 | 43.60119 |
| Jyribbcr  | 3.061856 | 2.479432 | 2.004008 | 0.5      | 2.082611 | 0.49505  | 1        | 0        | 6.0004   | 10.95238 | 6.335608 |
| Juzimagy  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.961538 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Lsctlezs  | 0        | 0.989716 | 0.5      | 0        | 1.666089 | 9.754986 | 2        | 0.978281 | 2        | 2        | 2        |
| Leccmzza  | 8.103093 | 29.13131 | 2.200401 | 2.477833 | 2.2      | 4.947037 | 2        | 0.980769 | 0.990099 | 6.904762 | 10.54871 |
| Ljjasqqc  | 2.061856 | 7.999634 | 1.502004 | 4.970443 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Lzaiqaan  | 1.515464 | 0.789716 | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0.478469 | 5        | 0        | 0        | 2.857143 | 1.45162  |
| Mqqujajo  | 0        | 0.29383  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2        | 1        | 1        | 0        | 0        | 4        |
| Mttilqng  | 0        | 0        | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Moeespzz  | 0        | 0        |          | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Mqrssfyv  | 1.530928 | 4.928012 | 3.003006 | 1.985222 | 5.041306 | 0.956938 | 0        | 2.884615 | 2.0002   | 0.97619  | 0.968529 |
| Pddittph  | 0        | 0.489716 | 4.501002 | 6.985222 | 0.502513 | 3        | 0        | 4.413176 | 1.010101 | 4.97619  | 0        |
| Ptysafqa  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Pooepqat  | 0        | 0        | 0.2      | 2        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Pggobrec  | 28.18557 | 11.9383  | 7.504008 | 65.91133 | 21.41306 | 45.69212 | 8        | 7.372226 | 19.0006  | 14.95238 | 23.17122 |
| Pdduojhd  | 0        | 0        | 0.300601 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Pttohsda  | 0        | 0.489716 | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0.29703  | 8.5      | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0.483092 |
| Pozzspgt  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.45162  |
| Pzzymuzz  | 0        | 7        | 1.001002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 6.060606 | 0        | 1        |
| Pzzyafff  | 21.27835 | 21.69091 | 20.30461 | 59.91133 | 67.41306 | 7.274788 | 3.5      | 28.23585 | 11.9808  | 26.76191 | 27.68998 |
| Pqqpmllr  | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Paaeatgo  | 12.15464 | 31.02379 | 7.501002 | 31.91133 | 13.08261 | 75.48766 | 7.5      | 8.920589 | 11.5307  | 21.90476 | 22.84968 |
| Pxdmggha  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.990099 | 0        | 0.970874 |
| Prasmzzl  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 2        | 0        | 0.956938 | 0        | 5.905737 | 3.515152 | 1.952381 | 0        |
| Pqqmryse  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 7.961538 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Rqnupabm  | 0.4      | 0        | 0.9      | 2.485222 | 1.005025 | 0.478469 | 0        | 1.442308 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Raazgzog  | 18.70619 | 18.09091 | 0.300401 | 2.492611 | 3.001005 | 8.947037 | 1.5      | 2.956588 | 3.0002   | 18.2381  | 19.64345 |
| Rhtzcory  | 0.309278 | 10.5     | 2.200401 | 1.098522 | 0        | 0.990099 | 0.5      | 0.480769 | 0        | 6        | 0        |
| Rhttdhica | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.077586 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Rzzdspwq  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.005025 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Rzodanzh  | 143.1856 | 17.62977 | 0        | 9.881773 | 239.0894 | 0        | 0        | 199.487  | 237.4228 | 2        | 222.552  |
| Rizealqe  | 0        | 0.2      | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Rzbeqrie  | 0        | 0        | 1.5      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Rzsaweqb  | 0        | 0        | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 1.270548 | 7        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Rzmenfpa  | 0        | 0        | 3.004008 | 1.492611 | 0        | 0.49505  | 4        | 1        | 0        | 0        | 1.453966 |
| Saziflzz  | 1        | 1        | 0        | 0        | 4.165223 | 0.478469 | 0        | 17.82516 | 7        | 0        | 0        |
| Saqvhaan  | 0.5      | 0.489716 | 0.501002 | 0.2      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.923077 | 0        | 0        | 5.801792 |
| Squscazd  | 0        | 0        | 0.501002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Sagisizi  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 0        | 0        |
| Sczospgt  | 0        | 0.605051 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Sqqgotie  | 0.515464 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Sqdgsooc  | 0        | 23.0404  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Sqdujker  | 3.561856 | 2.989533 | 2.001002 | 0.492611 | 0.502513 | 0.990099 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1        | 0.483092 |
| Sqgeddie  | 1        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.990099 | 0        | 1.449275 |
| Seaacssy  | 2.046392 | 0.195886 | 0.501002 | 0.492611 | 1.041306 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.49505  | 0.47619  | 0.968529 |
| Sabbddne  | 48.30928 | 38.9888  | 22.00802 | 153.8079 | 11.16522 | 26.69212 | 5        | 41.82506 | 18.9814  | 7.857143 | 18.22379 |
| Seegogie  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 1.010101 | 1.47619  | 0.485437 |
| Sqlethnu  | 1.015464 | 0.5      | 0.1002   | 0        | 1.041306 | 0        | 0        | 2.432407 | 0.5      | 1.47619  | 0.968529 |
| Sderpqti  | 16.51546 | 1        | 0        | 72.88177 | 15.08261 | 3.894074 | 6        | 27.7867  | 27.0008  | 27.80952 | 20.21441 |
| Tajadolz  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0.693069 | 1        | 1.490099 | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Tanggrqc  | 7.07732  | 0        | 0.200401 | 0.992611 | 1.041306 | 0        | 0        | 3.956563 | 9.505151 | 0        | 5.45162  |
| Tazaqqfi  | 0        | 0.5      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Tzraogfi  | 4.092784 | 3.979432 | 8.002004 | 6.985222 | 1        | 3        | 0        | 0        | 1.505151 | 0.97619  | 0        |
| Tssaspzq  | 0        | 0.1      | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Tzzmltte  | 23.09278 | 12.48898 | 8.504008 | 1.5      | 0        | 48.59657 | 3.5      | 1.5      | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Traapraz  | 0        | 0        | 2        | 4.070443 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Trrfrepq  | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Vawwpyao  | 0        | 0        | 0.751002 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Vegolaqa  | 0        | 0.489716 | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 0        |
| Vqolbigl  | 9.2      | 0.195886 | 2.251002 | 1        | 17.17527 | 26.89407 | 11.5     | 12.90815 | 6.990099 | 6        | 5.466184 |
| Xwntspzz  | 0        | 4        | 0        | 0        | 0        | 5.451987 | 1        | 0        | 0        | 4        | 0        |
| Xqntezzg  | 0.7      | 11.5303  | 0.800601 | 0        | 0        | 2.958667 | 0.7      | 0.2      | 3.990299 | 6.47619  | 6.04345  |



# ENVIRONMENTAL DATA:
| sites  | sites1   | sites2   | sites3   | sites4   | sites5   | sites6   | sites7   | sites8   | sites9   | sites10  | sites11  |
|--------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| Zone   | A        | B        | C        | D        | A        | B        | C        | D        | A        | B        | C        |
| Piun   | 2567     | 2567     | 2567     | 2567     | 3121     | 3121     | 3121     | 3121     | 3400     | 3400     | 3400     |
| Mznst  | 8.992345 | 9.413166 | 7.559753 | 9.496557 | 8.228341 | 10.67693 | 7.847657 | 8.524946 | 8.146352 | 9.177983 | 9.389186 |
| Ginr   | 3.511686 | 5.866005 | 5.013677 | 4.281403 | 3.796707 | 6.290231 | 4.460385 | 3.432576 | 3.256415 | 5.205405 | 6.847782 |
| Wmty   | -2.38901 | -1.05753 | -0.63847 | -1.56664 | -0.21446 | -3.18814 | -1.77833 | -0.0624  | -1.4973  | -2.03845 | -1.1768  |
| Skin   | 7.288117 | 8.427755 | 6.74688  | 6.913534 | 6.191946 | 8.931979 | 5.92338  | 5.621611 | 5.169905 | 7.499586 | 7.211062 |
| Soax   | 10.17934 | 11.41033 | 8.192583 | 11.05854 | 8.998501 | 14.08503 | 8.046209 | 8.077263 | 8.805485 | 10.6972  | 10.61082 |
| Bman   | 2.143564 | 3.745415 | 3.960193 | 1.927123 | 2.160199 | 2.634795 | 2.635866 | 2.120545 | 1.761974 | 2.972877 | 3.847655 |
| Btol   | -2.63    | -2.30076 | -1.12778 | -1.68521 | -0.2358  | -4.42905 | -2.52269 | -0.0765  | -1.60615 | -2.87471 | -2.06277 |
| Stmpn  | -0.32163 | 1.038842 | 0.453161 | -0.37127 | -0.06113 | -0.28731 | -0.11644 | -0.08511 | -0.69595 | -0.41739 | -0.29912 |
| Sopel  | -0.30077 | 2.265062 | 0.859361 | -0.35171 | -0.04794 | 1.196628 | 0.54414  | -0.07218 | -0.6766  | 0.324572 | -0.28255 |
| Dsmal  | 1.1      | 2.3      | 2.6      | 1.9      | 2.1      | 3.4      | 2.1      | 2.2      | 1.9      | 1.8      | 1.6      |
| Dtre   | 123      | 121      | 567      | 789      | 434      | 123      | 123      | 456      | 678      | 765      | 556      |
| Daat0  | 165      | 156      | 163      | 169      | 169      | 157      | 182      | 182      | 182      | 162      | 162      |
| Bsl    | 112      | 140      | 180      | 130      | 160      | 189      | 190      | 320      | 350      | 556      | 675      |
| Aagmon | 8.719253 | 9.219035 | 7.972462 | 8.52034  | 8.395065 | 10.35541 | 7.645433 | 8.373109 | 7.429683 | 9.160949 | 9.173563 |
| Aagmdx | 11.64418 | 12.28107 | 9.311358 | 12.78087 | 10.73138 | 14.5355  | 9.508062 | 11.35813 | 10.94872 | 11.82305 | 12.33025 |

# CODE:
library(vegan)
example.cca <- cca(community_data~Zone+Piun+Mznst+Ginr+Wmty+Skin+Soax+Bman+Btol+Stmpn, 
                  environmental_data) 
plot.example.cca <- ordiplot(example.cca, type="text", scaling=1)
```

[image: Canonical correspondence analysis]

Comment: It is hard for us to comment without more information.  Could you please post the code that made your plot along with some data so that we can recreate your display?  Please use `dput` to provide the relevant data. It might also be good to post an image of your display.

Comment: This now seems like a good & on topic question to me. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: Perhaps making a more general title such as e.g. "Displaying large number of text labels on scatter plot" could attract more attention to this question. (@gung)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [ggvegan](https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan/) and [ggrepel](https://github.com/slowkow/ggrepel/)

```
library("vegan")
library("ggvegan")
library("cowplot")
library("ggrepel")
data(varespec, varechem)
vare.cca <- cca(varespec, varechem)

obj <- fortify(vare.cca)
want <- obj$Score %in% c("species", "sites")

autoplot(vare.cca) +  geom_text(data = obj[want, , drop = FALSE ],
                                aes(x = Dim1, y = Dim2, label = Label,
                                colour = Score))
```

[image]

ggrepel:

```
autoplot(vare.cca) +  geom_text_repel(data = obj[want, , drop = FALSE ],
                  aes(x = Dim1, y = Dim2, label = Label,
                      colour = Score))
```

[image]

Notebook [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/saketkc/notebooks/blob/master/R/CCA--ggvegan.ipynb)